# Laravel's dd on ajax called methods returns always empty attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm having pain with an ajax called method.

First the same request as above :

```
$usersData = User::where('name', 'like', $queryString . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', $queryString . '%')
            ->orWhere('username', 'like', $queryString . '%')
            ->when($limit > 0 || $offset > 0, function ($usersData) use ($limit, $offset) {
                $usersData->take($limit)->skip($offset);

            })
            ->with(array('roles'=>function($query){
                $query->select('name');
            }))
            ->get();
```

works perfectly in the index method, the dd is correct and 'roles' contain just the 'name' field BUT if i call exactly the same request 'roles' contain ALL attributes and dd does'nt work i'm forced to make a console.log of my datas I'm going mad !!!

Here is the complete function :

```
public function ajaxQuery(Request $request): string
{

    $queryString = $request->input('queryString');
    $offset = $request->input('offset');
    $limit = $request->input('limit');


    $usersData = User::where('name', 'like', $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere('username', 'like', $queryString . '%')
        ->when($limit > 0 || $offset > 0, function ($usersData) use ($limit, $offset) {
            $usersData->take($limit)->skip($offset);
        })
        ->with(array('roles'=>function($query){
            $query->select('name');
        }))
        ->get();
        //->toJson();

    foreach ($usersData as $key =>$user){
        //$v['roles'] = $v['roles'][0]['name'];
        //dd($v);
        //$user->role = $user->role[0]['name'];
        //dd($user->role[0]['name']);
        //dd($user);
    }

    //$usersDatas['data'] = json_decode($usersData, true);
    $usersDatas['data'] = $usersData;


    $usersDatas['count'] = $usersData = User::where('name', 'like', $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere('username', 'like', $queryString . '%')->get()->count();

    $usersDatas = json_encode($usersDatas);

    return $usersDatas;

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show me what you got when you use `dd();` in ajax call?

Comment: Try `return $usersData;` instead of `dd();`. We use return statement when we use an ajax call! Hope this helps you.

Comment: I know that thanks it's just to debug

Comment: So still you get empty data if you use return statement?

Comment: Try: `->with(array('roles'=>function($query){
                $query->select(['name', 'id']);
            }))`

Comment: I tried your solution but it's like the selected fields parameter was ignored the roles array contain all the fields, I copied paste the code in the index method and it's perfect, I'm going mad !

Comment: So is my solution worked or not?

Comment: No it's ignored it's like there is a cache even if I tried to clear cache.

Comment: I thing you need to `echo` out your result passed to `$usersDatas`, so just try this at the bottom of your function: `echo $usersDatas; die;`

Comment: Sure it's the only way to see what the ajax returns I'll find a best tool to debug my ajax results... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you eager load specific columns (like you did with "roles"), you need to  specify the id column in the list of columns.

From [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> You may not always need every column from the relationships you are
>   retrieving. For this reason, Eloquent allows you to specify which
>   columns of the relationship you would like to retrieve:
>
> $users = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();
>
> When using this feature, you should always include the id column in
>   the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

```
$usersData = User::where('name', 'like', $queryString . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', $queryString . '%')
            ->orWhere('username', 'like', $queryString . '%')
            ->when($limit > 0 || $offset > 0, function ($usersData) use ($limit, $offset) {
                $usersData->take($limit)->skip($offset);
            })
            ->with(array('roles'=>function($query){
                $query->select(['name', 'id']);
            }))
            ->get();
```

Comment: No effect it's like there is a cache anywhere

Comment: Thanks it works now it's a kinda weird cache problem I think